# How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for HibernateGormStaticApi when running integration test in Grails?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, grails, groovy

I'm writing Spock Integration tests for a web application on Grails 2.4.4 with Postgresql 9.4, and am stuck on the error below. I'm including the test Spec and the part of the code where the error is thrown. This error is oddly happening only at my machine, that is running Lubuntu 14.10. The test runs fine at my colleague's machine, which is also Lubuntu 14.10. I have copied his project workspace and grails sdk to my machine, with no change in results. I appreciate any help anyone can spare.

```
Failure:  br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.AutorizaPassagemControllerIntegrationSpec |  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/HibernateGormStaticApi$6
        at br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.autorizacao.AutorizacaoPassante.afterInsert(AutorizacaoPassante.groovy:65)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.EventTriggerCaller$MethodCaller.call(EventTriggerCaller.java:153)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.EventTriggerCaller.call(EventTriggerCaller.java:96)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
        at br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.test.SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarAutorizacaoPassanteVisitante(SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.groovy:514)
        at br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.AutorizaPassagemControllerIntegrationSpec.setupSpec(AutorizaPassagemControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy:41) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi$6
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        ... 6 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:450)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        ... 9 more
```

My installed plugins (output from 'grails list-plugins'):

```
Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
cache               1.1.8            --  Cache Plugin
hibernate4          4.3.6.1          --  Hibernate 4 for Grails
plastic-criteria    1.5.1            --  Plastic Criteria Plugin
platform-core       1.0.0            --  Plugin Platform Core
release             3.0.1            --  Release Plugin
rest-client-builder 1.0.3            --  REST Client Builder Plugin
sagui-controleacesso0.1              --  Sagui Controleacesso Plugin
sagui-core          1.0-SNAPSHOT     --  Sagui Core Plugin
spring-security-core2.0-RC4          --  Spring Security Core Plugin
tomcat              7.0.55           --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig

To find more info about plugin type 'grails plugin-info [NAME]'

To install type 'grails install-plugin [NAME] [VERSION]'

For further info visit http://grails.org/Plugins
```

Class where the error is thrown (AutorizacaoPassante):

```
package br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.autorizacao

import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.controle.ControleAutorizacao
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.provisoria.MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria

    /**
     * Classe de domínio que descreve uma autorização de passante. Pode autorizar uma passagem independente de vínculo.
     * Associa uma mídia de identificação a uma unidade organizacional, opcionalmente um veículo (somente para passante
     * visitante), e um periodo de validade.
     *
     * @author Erick, Francisco, Jorge.
     * @since 10/12/2014
     */
    class AutorizacaoPassante implements Comparable<AutorizacaoPassante>{

        String id
        Date dateCreated // Data em que o registro foi criado.
        Date inicioAutorizacao // Data em que a autorização se inicia.
        Date fimAutorizacao // Data em que a autorização termina.
        String observacao
        Boolean ativo
        MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria midiaProvisoria

        static constraints = {
            observacao(nullable: true, blank: true, widget: "textarea")
            inicioAutorizacao(nullable: false)
            fimAutorizacao(nullable: false)
            ativo(nullable: false)
            midiaProvisoria(nullable: false)
        }

        static mapping = {
            id (generator: "uuid")
            table (schema: "controleacesso")
        }

        @Override
        int compareTo(AutorizacaoPassante autorizacaoPassante) {
            return  id <=> autorizacaoPassante.id
        }

        def beforeValidate() {

            def podeSerSalvo = true

            def autorizacao = AutorizacaoPassante.findByMidiaProvisoriaAndAtivo(this.midiaProvisoria,true)

            if(autorizacao && autorizacao.compareTo(this)!=0)
                podeSerSalvo =  false

            if (!podeSerSalvo) {
                this.errors.reject('erro.midia.midiaJaPossuiAutorizacaoAtiva')
                this.errors.rejectValue('midia', 'erro.midia.midiaJaPossuiAutorizacaoAtiva')
            }
        }

        private def adicionarAutorizacaoTabelaControle(){
            if (new ControleAutorizacao(autorizacao: this).save(flush: true))
                log.info("controleAutorizacao inserido: ${this.id}")
        }


        def afterInsert(){
            withNewSession {    // Line 65, where the error is thrown.
                if (this.ativo)
                    adicionarAutorizacaoTabelaControle()
            }
        }

        def afterUpdate(){
            withNewSession {
                if (this.ativo)
                        adicionarAutorizacaoTabelaControle()
                else{
                    if (ControleAutorizacao.findByAutorizacao(this).delete(flush: true))
                        log.info("controleAutorizacao removido: ${this.id}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class:

```
package br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso

import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.dispositivo.DispositivoAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.test.SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import spock.lang.Shared

class AutorizaPassagemControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    static transactional = true

    AutorizaPassagemController controller = new AutorizaPassagemController()

    @Shared def visitante
    @Shared def estado
    @Shared def midia
    @Shared def tipoLeitor
    @Shared def tipoDispositivo
    @Shared def dispositivo
    @Shared def leitor
    @Shared def grupoLeitor
    @Shared def tipoUnidade
    @Shared def unidade
    @Shared def autorizacao

    def setupSpec() {

        visitante = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarPassanteVisitante("Visitante 1", "12234344",TipoDocumento.CPF)
        estado = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarEstadoMidiaIdentificacao("Estado de midia de identificação ativo", true)
        midia = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarMidiaProvisoria("1234",estado)
        tipoLeitor = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarTipoLeitorAcesso("Leitor tipo não-urna.", false)
        tipoDispositivo = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarTipoDispositivoAcesso("Tipo de dispositivo de acesso teste.")
        dispositivo = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarDispositivoAcesso("Dispositivo teste.", "3456", tipoDispositivo)
        leitor = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarLeitorAcesso("Leitor teste","2345",0,1,true, tipoLeitor,
                DirecaoAcesso.BIDIRECIONAL, dispositivo)
        grupoLeitor = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarGrupoLeitorAcesso("Grupo teste 1.", [leitor])
        tipoUnidade = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarTipoUnidadeOrganizacional("Unidade teste.")
        unidade = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarUnidadeOrganizacional("Unidade teste.", "ET", "Portaria 1",Common.criaData(2014,1,1), Common.criaData(2015,1,1), tipoUnidade)
        autorizacao = SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil.adicionarAutorizacaoPassanteVisitante(visitante,unidade,Common.criaData(2010,1,1),
        Common.criaData(2015,1,1),midia)  // Line 41, where the exception is thrown.

    }

    void "autorizaPassagem deve autorizar Tag em uma passagem válida."() {

        setup:
        def codigoLeitor = "2345"
        def codigoMidia = "1234"
        def dispositivoId = DispositivoAcesso.findByCodigo("3456")?.id
        def dataOcorrencia = "01/01/2015 00:00:00"
        JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

        controller.request.parameters = [codigoMidia: codigoMidia, codigoLeitor: codigoLeitor, data: dataOcorrencia, dispositivoId: dispositivoId]

        when:
        controller.autorizarPassagem()
        def retornoAutorizarPassagem =  controller.response.contentAsString as String
        def retornoMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(retornoAutorizarPassagem) as Map
        then:
        retornoMap==["EVENTO":"1", "FXCREDITO":"0", "MSG":"Teste", "NIVEL":"1"]
    }
}
```

The test utility methods class:

```
package br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.test

import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.acl.AplicacaoPoliticaAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.acl.PoliticaAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.acl.TabelaHorarioPoliticaAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.autorizacao.AutorizacaoPassante
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.autorizacao.AutorizacaoPassantePessoa
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.autorizacao.AutorizacaoPassanteVisitante
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.dispositivo.DispositivoAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.dispositivo.TipoDispositivoAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.dispositivo.leitor.GrupoLeitorAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.dispositivo.leitor.LeitorAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.dispositivo.leitor.TipoLeitorAcesso
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.EstadoMidiaIdentificacao
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.MidiaIdentificacao
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.RegistroMudancaEstadoMidiaIdentificacao
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.permanente.MidiaIdentificacaoPermanenteCartao
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.permanente.MidiaIdentificacaoPermanenteTag
import br.ufscar.sagui.controleacesso.midia.provisoria.MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria
import br.ufscar.sagui.core.Pessoa
import br.ufscar.sagui.core.TipoUnidadeOrganizacional
import br.ufscar.sagui.core.UnidadeOrganizacional
import br.ufscar.sagui.core.Vinculo
import br.ufscar.sagui.core.grupo.Grupo
import org.springframework.util.Assert

/**
 * Created by francisco on 29/01/2015.
 */

class SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil {

    static GrupoLeitorAcesso adicionarGrupoLeitorAcesso(String nomeGrupo, List<LeitorAcesso> leitores = []){

        Assert.notNull nomeGrupo, "O objeto [nomeGrupo] não pode ser nulo"

        def grupo = new GrupoLeitorAcesso()
        grupo.nomeGrupo = nomeGrupo
        grupo.leitores = (leitores as Set)

        if(grupo.save(flush: true)){
            println("Grupo leitor acesso com id [${grupo.id}] salvo.")
        }
        else{
            println("Falha ao salvar o grupo de leitores de acesso [${grupo}].")
            println(grupo.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return grupo
    }

    static TipoLeitorAcesso adicionarTipoLeitorAcesso (String nome, Boolean urna) {
        Assert.notNull(nome, "Nome nulo.")
        Assert.notNull(urna, "Urna nula.")

        def tipoLeitor = new TipoLeitorAcesso(nome: nome, urna: urna)

        if (tipoLeitor.save()) {
            println("Tipo de leitor de acesso com id [${tipoLeitor.id}] salvo.")
        } else{
            println("Falha ao salvar tipo de leitor de acesso [${tipoLeitor}].")
            println(tipoLeitor.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return tipoLeitor
    }
    static LeitorAcesso adicionarLeitorAcesso(String nomeLeitor,String codigo, Integer nivelOrigem, Integer nivelDestino,Boolean permitirPassanteVisitante, TipoLeitorAcesso tipo,
                                       DirecaoAcesso direcaoAcesso,DispositivoAcesso dispositivo){

        Assert.notNull nomeLeitor, "O objeto [nomeLeitor] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull nivelOrigem, "O objeto [nivelOrigem] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull nivelDestino, "O objeto [nivelDestino] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull permitirPassanteVisitante, "O objeto [permitirPassanteVisitante] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull tipo, "O objeto [tipo] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull direcaoAcesso, "O objeto [direcaoAcesso] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull codigo, "O objeto [codigo] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull dispositivo, "O objeto [dispositivo] não pode ser nulo"

        def leitor = new LeitorAcesso()
        leitor.nome = nomeLeitor
        leitor.nivelDestino = nivelDestino
        leitor.nivelOrigem = nivelOrigem
        leitor.permitirPassanteVisitante = permitirPassanteVisitante
        leitor.tipo = tipo
        leitor.direcaoAcesso = direcaoAcesso
        leitor.codigo = codigo
        leitor.dispositivo = dispositivo

        if(leitor.save()){
            println("Leitor de acesso com id [${leitor.id}] salvo.")
        }
        else{
            println("Falha ao salvar leitor de acesso [${leitor}].")
            println(leitor.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return leitor
    }

    static TipoDispositivoAcesso adicionarTipoDispositivoAcesso(String nome){
        def dispositivo = new TipoDispositivoAcesso(nome: nome)

        if (dispositivo.save(flush: true)){
            println("Tipo de dispositivo de acesso com id [${dispositivo.id}] salvo.")
        }else{
            println("Falha ao salvar tipo de dispositivo de acesso [${dispositivo}]")
            println(dispositivo.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return  dispositivo
    }
    static TipoUnidadeOrganizacional adicionarTipoUnidadeOrganizacional(String nome){
        def tipo = new TipoUnidadeOrganizacional(nome: nome)

        if (tipo.save(flush: true)){
            println("Tipo de unidade organizacional com id [${tipo.id}] salva.")
        }else{
            println("Falha ao salvar o tipo de unidade organizacional [${tipo}].")
            println(tipo.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return tipo
    }
    static UnidadeOrganizacional adicionarUnidadeOrganizacional(String nome, String sigla, String portaria, Date inicio,
                                                                Date fim, TipoUnidadeOrganizacional tipo){

        def unidade = new UnidadeOrganizacional(nome: nome, sigla: sigla, portariaCriacao: portaria,
                inicioFuncionamento: inicio, fimFuncionamento: fim, tipo: tipo)

        if (unidade.save(flush: true)){
            println("Unidade organizacional com id [${unidade.id}] salva.")
        } else{
            println("Falha ao salvar a unidade organizacional [${unidade}].")
            println(unidade.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return unidade
    }

    static DispositivoAcesso adicionarDispositivoAcesso(String nomeDispositivo,String codigo, TipoDispositivoAcesso tipo){

        Assert.notNull nomeDispositivo, "O objeto [nomeDispositivo] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull codigo, "O objeto [codigo] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull tipo, "O objeto [tipo] não pode ser nulo"

        def dispositivo = new DispositivoAcesso()
        dispositivo.nome = nomeDispositivo
        dispositivo.codigo=codigo
        dispositivo.tipo = tipo

        if(dispositivo.save(flush: true)){
            println("Dispositivo de acesso com id [${dispositivo.id}] salvo.")
        }
        else{
            println("Erro ao salvar dispositivo de acesso [${dispositivo}].")
            println(dispositivo.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return dispositivo
    }

    static PassanteVisitante adicionarPassanteVisitante(String nome, String documento, TipoDocumento tipoDocumento, String observacao = null){

        Assert.notNull nome, "A literal [nome] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull documento, "O literal [documento] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull tipoDocumento, "O objeto [tipoDocumento] não pode ser nulo"

        def visitante = new PassanteVisitante()
        visitante.setNome(nome)
        visitante.setDocumento(documento)
        visitante.setTipoDocumento(tipoDocumento)
        visitante.setObservacao(observacao)


        if (visitante.save()) {
            println("Passante Visitante com id [${visitante.id}] salvo.")
        } else {
            println("Falha ao salvar o passante visitante [${visitante}].")
            println(visitante.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return visitante
    }

    static PassantePessoa adicionarPassantePessoa(Pessoa pessoa){

        Assert.notNull pessoa, "O objeto [pessoa] não pode ser nulo"

        def passante = new PassantePessoa(pessoa: pessoa)

        if(passante.save(flush: true)){
            println("Passante pessoa com id [${passante.id}] salvo.")
        }
        else{
            println("Falha ao salvar passante pessoa [${passante}]")
            println(passante.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return passante
    }

    static PoliticaAcesso adicionarPoliticaAcesso(String nomePolitica,Boolean antipassBack, Boolean controlarRota, Boolean ativa, Boolean negar,GrupoLeitorAcesso grupoLeitorAcesso,String observacao = null){

        Assert.notNull nomePolitica, "O objeto [nomePolitica] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull antipassBack, "O objeto [antipassBack] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull controlarRota, "O objeto [controlarRota] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull ativa, "O objeto [ativar] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull negar, "O objeto [negar] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull grupoLeitorAcesso, "O objeto [grupoLeitorAcesso] não pode ser nulo"

        def politica = new PoliticaAcesso()
        politica.antipassBack = antipassBack
        politica.ativa = ativa
        politica.negar = negar
        politica.controlarRota = controlarRota
        politica.grupoLeitorAcesso = grupoLeitorAcesso
        politica.observacao = observacao
        politica.nome = nomePolitica

        if(politica.save(flush: true)){
            println("Politica de acesso com id [${politica.id}] salva.")
        }
        else{
            println("Falha ao salvar politica de acesso [${politica}].")
            println(politica.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return politica
    }

    static TabelaHorarioPoliticaAcesso adicionarTabelaHorarioPoliticaAcesso(Integer diaSemana,Integer horaInicio, Integer minutoInicio, Integer horaFim, Integer minutoFim,PoliticaAcesso politicaAcesso){

        Assert.notNull diaSemana, "O objeto [diaSemana] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull horaInicio, "O objeto [horaInicio] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull minutoInicio, "O objeto [minutoInicio] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull horaFim, "O objeto [horaFim] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull minutoFim, "O objeto [minutoFim] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull politicaAcesso, "O objeto [politicaAcesso] não pode ser nulo"

        def tabela = new TabelaHorarioPoliticaAcesso()
        tabela.diaSemana = diaSemana
        tabela.horaInicio = horaInicio
        tabela.minutoInicio = minutoInicio
        tabela.horaFim = horaFim
        tabela.minutoFim = minutoFim
        tabela.politicaAcesso = politicaAcesso

        if(tabela.save(flush: true)){
            println("Tabela de horario com id [${tabela.id}] salva.")
        }
        else{
            println("Falha ao salvar tabela de horario [${tabela}].")
            println(tabela.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return tabela
    }

    static AplicacaoPoliticaAcesso adicionarAplicacaoPoliticaAcesso(PoliticaAcesso politicaAcesso, Grupo grupo , Passante passante, Boolean ativo){

        Assert.notNull politicaAcesso, "O objeto [politicaAcesso] não pode ser nulo"
        if((grupo == null && passante == null)||(grupo != null && passante != null))
            Assert.fail "O objeto [grupo] e [passante] não podem ser nulos nem verdadeiros ao mesmo tempo"
        Assert.notNull ativo, "O boleano [ativo] não pode ser nulo"


        def aplicacaoPoliticaAcesso = new AplicacaoPoliticaAcesso(politicaAcesso: politicaAcesso, grupo: grupo,
                passante: passante, ativo: ativo)

        if(aplicacaoPoliticaAcesso.save(flush: true)){
            println("Aplicacao de política de acesso com id [${aplicacaoPoliticaAcesso.id}] salva.")
        }
        else{
            println("Falha ao salvar aplicacao de política de acesso [${aplicacaoPoliticaAcesso}].")
            println(aplicacaoPoliticaAcesso.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return aplicacaoPoliticaAcesso
    }

    static AutorizacaoPassanteVisitante adicionarAutorizacaoPassanteVisitante(PassanteVisitante visitante, UnidadeOrganizacional unidade, Date inicioAutorizacao, Date fimAutorizacao, MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria midiaProvisoria, Veiculo veiculo = null, String observacao = null, Boolean ativo = true){

        Assert.notNull visitante, "O objeto [visitante] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull unidade, "O objeto [unidade] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull inicioAutorizacao, "O objeto [inicioAutorizacao] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull fimAutorizacao, "O objeto [fimAutorizacao] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull midiaProvisoria, "O objeto [MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria] não pode ser nulo"

        def autorizacao = new AutorizacaoPassanteVisitante()
        autorizacao.passanteVisitante = visitante
        autorizacao.unidadeOrganizacionalDestino = unidade
        autorizacao.inicioAutorizacao = inicioAutorizacao
        autorizacao.fimAutorizacao = fimAutorizacao
        autorizacao.midiaProvisoria = midiaProvisoria

        autorizacao.veiculoPassanteVisitante = veiculo
        autorizacao.ativo = ativo
        autorizacao.observacao = observacao

        //Cria registro que relaciona visitante e veiculo
        if(veiculo&&visitante)
            adicionarPassanteVisitanteVeiculo(visitante,veiculo)

        if (autorizacao.save(flush: true)) {
           println("Autorizacao passante visitante com id [${autorizacao.id}] salva.")
        } else {
            println("Falha ao salvar autorizacao passante visitante [${autorizacao}].")
            println(autorizacao.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return autorizacao
    }

    static AutorizacaoPassantePessoa adicionarAutorizacaoPassantePessoa(PassantePessoa passantePessoa, Date inicioAutorizacao,  Date fimAutorizacao, String observacao = null, Boolean ativo = true, MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria midiaProvisoria){

        Assert.notNull passantePessoa, "O objeto [visitante] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull inicioAutorizacao, "O objeto [inicioAutorizacao] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull fimAutorizacao, "O objeto [fimAutorizacao] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull midiaProvisoria, "O objeto [MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria] não pode ser nulo"

        def autorizacao = new AutorizacaoPassantePessoa()
        autorizacao.passantePessoa = passantePessoa
        autorizacao.inicioAutorizacao = inicioAutorizacao
        autorizacao.fimAutorizacao = fimAutorizacao
        autorizacao.midiaProvisoria = midiaProvisoria

        autorizacao.ativo = ativo
        autorizacao.observacao = observacao

        if (autorizacao.save(flush: true)) {
            println("Autorizacao Passante Pessoa com id [${autorizacao.id}] salva.")
        } else {
            println("Falha ao salvar autorizaçao passante pessoa [${autorizacao}].")
            println(autorizacao.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return autorizacao
    }

    static EstadoMidiaIdentificacao adicionarEstadoMidiaIdentificacao(String nome, Boolean ativo){
        def midia = new EstadoMidiaIdentificacao(nome: nome, ativo: ativo,)

        if(midia.save(flush: true)){
            println("Estado de midia de identificação com id [${midia.id}] salvo." )
        } else {
            println("Falha ao salvar o estado de midia de identificação [${midia}].")
            println(midia.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return midia
    }

    static MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria adicionarMidiaProvisoria(String codigoMidia, EstadoMidiaIdentificacao estado) {

        Assert.notNull codigoMidia, "O objeto [codigoMidia] não pode ser nulo"
        Assert.notNull estado, "O objeto [estado] não pode ser nulo"

        def midiaProvisoria = new MidiaIdentificacaoProvisoria()
        midiaProvisoria.estadoMidiaIdentificacao = estado
        midiaProvisoria.codigo = codigoMidia

        if (midiaProvisoria.save(flush: true)) {
            println("Midia de identificação provisória com id [${midiaProvisoria?.id}] salva.")
        } else {
            println("Falha ao salvar a midia de identificaçao provisoria com id [${midiaProvisoria}].")
            println(midiaProvisoria.getErrors())
            return null
        }
        return midiaProvisoria
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: `SaguiControleAcessoTestUtil` should be added as well. Also specify which line number in test throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro! I pointed to the line in the test where the exception occurs, and also added the test util class. This class was quite big, so I had to trim it a little.

Comment: have you tried using `AutorizacaoPassante.withNewSession { ... }` in `afterInsert()`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the hibernate plugin. I removed it from the .m2 folder, and with run-app it was installed again. That solved the issue. It must have been corrupted.

Thanks!